# How to create a BBC style (facebox?) help popup

Tags: facebox

I have tried to take apart the code, but can't seem to replicate it.

On the BBC weather homepage, http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/, you will see a little help quetionmark in a circle in the top right corner or some of the boxes. When you click on it, it brings up a nice help popup, that looks a little like facebox.

The main thing I like about this, is the little arrow that points back to the help button to the right of the container. Facebox is just a standard square.

If anyone knows how to replicate this, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

The effect is known as a modal window and was popularised primarily by the [Lightbox javascript library](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/). Nowadays, there are many libraries to create this kind of effect, but the most popular tend to use the [jQuery JavaScript framework](http://jquery.com/).

My personal favourite jQuery implementation is [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) (A light-weight, customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery 1.3 and 1.4). Look at the **Other Content Types** section [on their demo page](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html) for examples of something similar to that seen on BBC.

Comment: No matter which one you use, don't forget that IE6, modal divs and dropdowns (select) don't work very well together. Be warned.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this by using a hidden DIV on the page.  I then attached a javascript event to the icon (?) to toggle the visibility of the DIV.  For the shape of the 'pop-up', seems to me that could just be a background graphic.

I have an example of that on www.sitemills.com/prices.php if you're interested.  Fairly sure the javascript is embedded so you should be able to do a view-source.